# Why is the page reloading even after the event.preventDefault() is called?

Tags: javascript, html, fetch

This is the javascript code for the call to the API in localhost port 5000:

```
const button = document.querySelector('#submitButton')

const url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict"



button.addEventListener('click', async (event)=>{
    event.preventDefault()
    const fileInput = document.querySelector('#cardImage')

    let formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('file', fileInput.files[0])

    console.log(formData);

    let response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
    })
    .then(response=>{
        return response.json()
    })
    .catch(error=>{
        console.log(error)
    })

    console.log(response)
})
```

This is the HTML for the webpage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CardReader</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Card Reader</h1>
        <h3>Upload your card here</h3>
        <input type="file" name="cardImage" id="cardImage"><br/><br/>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submitButton">
    <div id="result"></div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am running the web page using Live Server on port 5500.
I'm unable to figure out why the fetch method call is reloading the webpage even after the `event.preventDefault()` call. Can anyone help me understand why and is there a way to solve this problem?

I have tried using the deprecated global event object and tried preventing the reload by calling  `event.preventDefault()` method in the catch block and then block as well but to no avail. For now I'm preventing reload using this window object's 'beforeunload' event.

```
const onConfirmRefresh = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return event.returnValue = "Are you sure you want to leave the page?";
}

window.addEventListener("beforeunload", onConfirmRefresh, { capture: true });
```

Comment: [I can't reproduce the behaviour you describe](https://jsbin.com/cegajuroqu/1/edit?html,output) with the code you provided. (Nor can I see any code that which would trigger navigation (even without JS) in the first place: You have no links or submit buttons, and no JS that does anything with the `location` object.

Comment: @Quentin I think this window reloading happened because of Live Server because when I opened the html file using the path instead of Live server I did not face any issue of reloading after triggering the button click event. I don't know why that is the case though.